# I cannot embed jquery within my html

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

Good day,

I do not know what to do with the scripts below - they are two possible solutions to creating up/down arrows (or plus minus icons) to a Bootstrap Accordion. I understand that whichever I use needs to be surrounded by   tags, but no combinations I have tried are giving me the desired result.

Please can you show me EXACTLY what needs to go before each chunk of script, and what needs to follow ie if I were looking at the source code of my page what would I be seeing where the jquery is concerned?

Alternatively, if I save each script as a .js file, what additional commands need to be included in the .js file.

Thanks very much in advance.

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
$(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find("i.indicator")
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

and

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Comment: at the end of your html document add this code and wrap them by <script type='text/javascript'> your codes </script>.

Comment: show the html structure!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dx5ax1hp/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Thank you T. Rahgooy I have already tried that solution. Guruprasad, my accordion is already full of text - standard twitter bootstrap 3 accordion with some styling but all original classes in place (id is accordion, class .panel-heading exists and so on) so I am confident that the way I am calling the jquery is to blame. For instance, shouldn't I have
   <script type='text/javascript'> $( document ).ready(function() {

Comment: My apologies, I hit return too soon.

Arun, are you saying I should put the below, as it appears here, in my html following that accordion?

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });
})
</script>

Comment: Guruprasad, I have "forked" a new jsfiddle with my own html - http://jsfiddle.net/hkjtn8h6/ - and I am not seeing the desired results - so perhaps an issue with my html after all?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to jfiddle, Arun. A great starting point and a wonderful tool. Then it was only working in jsfiddle but not on my site - and finally I realised I needed to call the snippet appear AFTER the min.js file has been called. It is all working perfectly now, so thank you everyone for your input.